# Change the color of panel underline

Tags: gnome, colors

No matter what I try I can't find a way to change the color of the underline, it's annoying because I don't really like the color blue and it overrides the underline or highlight for the panel on shell themes. If anyone has a way to remove this or change it's color to black then please tell me.

[image]

[image]

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak

Comment: If your curious as to how to change this color scheme it seems the only way to change this is to just find a suitable theme on https://www.gnome-look.org I personally use flat plat blue ironically enough because it looks nice and despite the name is not as blue as the default. you'll have to create a .Themes folder in your home directory and enable user themes in extensions.

Comment: Alright, it's been three years and I've just noticed this post is still here. THE SOLUTION is actually in editing the gnome-shell.css file that can be found under usr/share/gnome-shell or the same file in your theme of choice.

Comment: It should be the line called "box-shadow:" just under the line "button:focus, #panel .panel-button:checked". this only popped up one instance in the text editors find option. Just make sure to make a backup and use "sudo nautilus" from the terminal to edit it from the file manager.